# group by two columns and cumulative sum with lookback window of 6 months on date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Original dataset

```
userId     createDate                  grade
0          2016-05-08 22:00:49.673     2
0          2016-07-23 12:37:11.570     7
0          2017-01-03 12:05:33.060     7
1009       2016-06-27 09:28:19.677     5
1009       2016-07-23 12:37:11.570     8
1009       2017-01-03 12:05:33.060     9
1009       2017-02-08 16:17:17.547     4
2011       2016-11-03 14:30:25.390     6
2011       2016-12-15 21:06:14.730     11
2011       2017-01-04 20:22:31.423     2
2011       2017-08-08 16:17:17.547     7
```

I want rolling sum of grade for each user with lookback window of 6 months from createDate i.e (sum of all grades for that under 6 months from create date)
Expected:

```
userId     createDate                 
    0          2016-05-08 22:00:49.673     2
               2016-07-23 12:37:11.570     9
               2017-01-03 12:05:33.060     14
    1009       2016-06-27 09:28:19.677     5
               2016-07-23 12:37:11.570     13
               2017-01-03 12:05:33.060     17
               2017-02-08 16:17:17.547     13
    2011       2016-11-03 14:30:25.390     6
               2016-12-15 21:06:14.730     17
               2017-01-04 20:22:31.423     19
               2017-08-08 16:17:17.547     7
```

My current try is incorrect :

```
df.groupby(['userId','createDate'])['grade'].mean().groupby([pd.Grouper(level='userId'),pd.TimeGrouper('6M', level='createDate', closed = 'left')]).cumsum()
```

It gives me following result:

```
userId  createDate             
0       2016-05-08 22:00:49.673     2
        2016-07-23 12:37:11.570     9
        2017-01-03 12:05:33.060     7
1009    2016-06-27 09:28:19.677     5
        2016-07-23 12:37:11.570    13
        2017-01-03 12:05:33.060     9
        2017-02-08 16:17:17.547    13
2011    2016-11-03 14:30:25.390     6
        2016-12-15 21:06:14.730    17
        2017-01-04 20:22:31.423    19
        2017-08-08 16:17:17.547     7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `rolling sum` inside `apply` with offset of `180D` rather than 6 months because number of days in months tends to change every consecutive months. And rolling window must be a constant i.e.

```
df.groupby(['userId'])['createDate','grade'].apply(lambda x : x.set_index('createDate').rolling('180D').sum())

                                grade
userId createDate                    
0      2016-05-08 22:00:49.673    2.0
       2016-07-23 12:37:11.570    9.0
       2017-01-03 12:05:33.060   14.0
1009   2016-06-27 09:28:19.677    5.0
       2016-07-23 12:37:11.570   13.0
       2017-01-03 12:05:33.060   17.0
       2017-02-08 16:17:17.547   13.0
2011   2016-11-03 14:30:25.390    6.0
       2016-12-15 21:06:14.730   17.0
       2017-01-04 20:22:31.423   19.0
       2017-08-08 16:17:17.547    7.0
```

*Edit for comment:*

To look back 6 months ago the dates need to be sorted. So perhaps you might need `sort_values`

```
 df.groupby(['userId'])['createDate','grade'].apply(lambda x : \
            x.sort_values('createDate').set_index('createDate').rolling('180D').sum())
```

Edit based on @coldspeed's comment:

Using apply is a overkill, set the index first then use rolling sum :

```
df.set_index('createDate').groupby('userId').grade.rolling('‌​180D').sum()
```

Timings:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

%%timeit
df.set_index('createDate').groupby('userId').grade.rolling('180D').sum() 
100 loops, best of 3: 7.55 ms per loop

%%timeit
df.groupby(['userId'])['createDate','grade'].apply(lambda x : x.sort_values('createDate').set_index('createDate').rolling('180D').sum())
10 loops, best of 3: 19.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am getting this error when I apply on full dataset {ValueError: index must be monotonic}

Comment: Isn't the dates sorted? To look back 6 months ago they need to sorted. If they are not sorted it gives index must be monotonic.

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks a lot, appreciate it. My dataset is huge and taking a lot of time on r3.8x large instance. But I have marked it as right answer and upvoted it.

Comment: is there any faster way to do this? This one is still running on 14 million rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161781/discussion-between-dsl1990-and-dark).

Comment: @dsl1990 Try `df.set_index('createDate').groupby('userId').grade.rolling('180D').sum()`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Shall I add it to he answer ?

Comment: Go ahead. You may also like to do a timing comparison.

Comment: @COLDSPEED if you can add it as an answer, I will mark it as an answer. I have added comparison already. Thanks guys!

Comment: @dsl1990 You're welcome. And that's alright. Dark's answer is similar to mine, so I've done him the courtesy of adding it as a comment. You can consider my answer as his now. Happy coding.